# The speed of electron when neutron converts into proton and electron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, relativity

Neutron converts into an electron and a proton. After the reaction all of the remaining energy $E=782\ \mathrm{keV}$ is converted to the kinetic energy of the electron.  Electron mass is $9.11\cdot 10^{-31}\ \mathrm{kg}$. What is the speed of the electron?

Correct answer: $0.92c$.

Tried using $E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}}$ but I get $0.756c$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The relativistic kinetic energy equation is

$$ E_k = \frac{m_0 c^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} - m_0c^2 $$

(See [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/releng.html))

Comment: Oh yes completely forgot that second term.